# Is it possible to add images in the Text Editor?

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, text-editor

A little bit of context:
I've beeng working around some "interoperability" between Blender and other software/hardware like: Pure Data, reacTIVision, Arduino, Raspberry Pi, etc.

I toyed with doing some async things, "serving" from a virtualEnv and "clienting" connecting to, from Blender and vice versa.
I don't know if it is correct terminology here - 'embedding'(?) IPython. 
(interactive console from visualcode) to [Blender ipython.embed()] like described here: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_9/info_tips_and_tricks.html.

then, recentlly, I watched some cool features on Wolfram Mathematica. Really cool stuff. And, I kind of mixed stuff in my head wondering if something like this could be implemented by some hackery. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7kX7BuHSFI. I don't expect something like Wolfram Mathematica. I understand what that would imply. So I just want to open an image in the Text Editor. :)

What Ipython.latex is able to do, I imagined An autocompletion-like feature which throws and [Ipython-line [console]] inside the text editor to open up small image representation of what you are doing in the 3dscreen or whatever your data_base content is.

This would be useful, to keep track of the stuff in projects by having visual representation of objects without having to have them while you write them on your scripts. (objective-symbolic-python) :)

If someone has any idea, I'll apreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: It would really be easier to understand you if you made an effort to make no spelling mistakes. You are talking about complex things, with complex terminology, various names of software packages and technologies - it is hard to follow. It would be a lot easier if you made an effort to write the exact names of the things you are talking about, also capitalize the names to indicate they are names. It's not always clear. I tried to correct the text as well as I am able to, but I am afraid it is still not clear, it needs editing. I would recommend getting a spell check add-on for your browser.

Comment: thank you Martin, i feel sorry about :(  english is not my natural lenguaje, i do my best to explain myself, i'll take it on count. 
what wasnt clear, exactelly? so i can try to fix it.
I know there's may be little few persons that could answer to this and it might be trivial for those(may be). But dont know if they have time for it, i just want some hints on where to start.. itll be cool
and lastlly, ont forget the title of the question. this is preety much clear. and what im trying to achieve.

Comment: 'I toyed with doing some async things, "serving" from a virtualEnv and "clienting" connecting to, from Blender and vice versa.' This could be made clearer. The purpose of what you are doing could also be described in more detail. As far as images in the Text Editor go it would probably be possible to do with OpenGL(see: [bgl](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_4/bgl.html)), you can also look into putting images in the UI, you can put stuff in the side panel or maybe make a pop-up. Try looking into bpy layout.template_preview and working with UI in bpy in general.

Comment: well, dont know, this is actually what im doing, toying, playing if you prefeer, The main purpose is just satisfy my curiosity about: is it blender-and-python capable of doing such or such thing that i'd like it to be able. 
If you want to know more about what is exactelly what im doing or what is it for? I simply dont know. having fun
Thanks for the hints, ill check it up. these are some good ideas. 
¿do you know how do get output to terminal when press [ctrl]+[space] in tex editor. [autocompletion], wich is that oop?  where is called from? app.debugg=True but nothing. thanks

Comment: Google knows. Check [this](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/code_autocomplete) out.

Comment: hm, thats what i was wanting to avoid, to dig up on this again :) but its a good one thank you. Yeah im shure there's the function call im looking for. i was. 
then it only least to know if i can break the thext editor. :D.
thank you for the help. ill see what comes up.

Comment: well im here now... I thinked on these ideas. bgl and GL to draw on top, also I thinked it as a layout, but here it where i think itll be placed somehow still figuring it out. 
https://github.com/JacquesLucke/code_autocomplete/blob/master/graphics/text_box.py

Comment: yep a Gl thing from rectangle(). Thank you Martin. i think i got it. nor the [console line] in the text editor with Ipython. 
But a colored Gl thing [image] on the text editor.

Comment: It is OpenGL, or bgl not Gl - that looks like GI that is for 'Global Illumination' that has nothing to do with this. If you are interested in coding you should get used to following the rules of languages. Seriously, that is hard to follow and understand.

Comment: i see, i read about pep compliance yesterday. i should used capitals GL in here. got it (y)

Comment: if someone followed this to this point, then [here](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/How_to/Add_an_icon) are some useful stuff. notice the here link. :)!